# Tkinter giving Import Error: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a 64 bit machine but because of some compatibility issues with other softwares i'm using 32 bit python(all softwares related to my application are 32 bit). When I'm trying to run my application It's giving me  following error for tkinter:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Can anyone suggest me a solution.

Comment: could you post the sourcecode?

Comment: @user I can not, due to some some restrictions. It's giving me error at statement "import tkinter"itself, so I don't think code can help us

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error (under Python 2.7 32-bit on Windows 10) by removing the `_thinker.pyd` and `_tkinter.lib` files from my `python_script` folder. I later removed the `python_script` folder itself.